# Calculate Inv Chi Squared Java

Tags: java, math, statistics, apache-commons

Well I'm programming a test in java for pseudoRandom numbers for simulation subjet, and I need to calculate inverse of Chi squared, so I have alpha and degrees  [as you can see here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YolV6wYwO4uWek827C-P7kUtqBcqZS8a/view?usp=sharing).

the book I'm reading, uses Excel function [Excel ChiSQ.INV](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHISQ-INV-function-400DB556-62B3-472D-80B3-254723E7092F) like this:

`CHISQ.INV(probability,deg_freedom)`

`CHISQ.INV(0.025,39) = 58.12005973` <- THIS value is what i need to calculate

The thing is I'm using a table to calculate the chi squared, but I think there's some way to calculate with the computer, I found this Class but I still don't get how it works [ChiSquaredDistribution Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/ChiSquaredDistribution.html)

So the objetive is to calculate Chi Squared Inv with java or with a library for java.

```
ChiSquaredDistribution x2 = new ChiSquaredDistribution(1, 0.05);

System.out.println(x2.cumulativeProbability(1.96));
System.out.println(x2.getNumericalVariance());
```

output:

> 0.8384866815324579
>
> 2.0

Comment: Never used this class before, but if you need inverse Chi distribution, there is method [`ChiSquaredDistribution#inverseCumulativeProbability`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/ContinuousDistribution.html#inverseCumulativeProbability(double)) Inherited from interface [`ContinuousDistribution`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/ContinuousDistribution.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but could you show and example of code with the Class.

Comment: The same way as you use `x2.cumulativeProbability(1.96)`, you can use `x2.inverseCumulativeProbability(1.96)`. I wrote it into comment only, because I am not sure, this solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks so much, in order to calculate the value I asked, is 1-(alpha/2) = 1-(0.05/2) = 0.975 so in Java ChiSquaredDistribution x2 = new ChiSquaredDistribution(39);
        System.out.println( x2.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.975) );

Comment: Great. Feel free to post your research as answer, to make it visible to other people seeking for solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to calculate the chi squared function with 39 degrees of freedom and with 95% level of confidence, so alpha is 5%. [as you can see here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YolV6wYwO4uWek827C-P7kUtqBcqZS8a/view?usp=sharing)
This is the excel function :

```
CHISQ.INV(probability,deg_freedom)
CHISQ.INV(0.025,39) = 58.12005973
```

In order to calculate the value I asked in java, is 1-(alpha/2) = 1-(0.05/2) = 0.975

so in Java using [Apache Commons Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/):

```
ChiSquaredDistribution x2 = new ChiSquaredDistribution( degreesOfFreedom );
double result = x2.inverseCumulativeProbability(alpha);

ChiSquaredDistribution x2 = new ChiSquaredDistribution(39);
System.out.println( x2.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.975) );
```

> Output:
>
> 58.12005973444771

the result seems almost the same as the excel function, may be the book is wrong (58.1200541) or is rounded.